# Mirrors, how can I prove a beam hits at a particular place

Tags: optics, geometric-optics, geometry

I have two mirrors (red segments) that are parallel, that have certain angle alpha with the horizontal line, and when the first mirror with a fixed center rotates it makes the second mirror move so that they stay parallel with each other.

[image]

The intersection between the blue line and the circle is at the point: R*cos(2*alpha),R*sin(2*alpha).

The equation for the line that passes through the second mirror (the one whose center is not fixed to the origin) is: y = sin(alpha)/cos(alpha)*x + 0.01/cos(alpha)

And to prove that the beam always lands on the center of the second mirror we need:

R*sin(2alpha) = sin(alpha)/cos(alpha)*R*cos(2*alpha) + 0.01/cos(alpha)

Which happens to be true for certain angles but not all. So this means the beam doesn't always hit the same place of the 2nd mirror.

And yet this isn't what happens in reality (the beam hits the same spot that it hit on the first miror on the second)? Where have I made a mistake?

Comment: The condition that the two mirrors are parallel allows the second mirror to be anywhere on the circle. You can place it so that the beam hits its center.

Answer (score 1):

Please clarify your question:
I suppose that the beam (or better its origin point) is not rotating with the mirrors and that it is drawn whit the green line. Otherwise, specify the beam origin and direction.

- If the beam is the ***green line***: why it should hit always the same place? Take the extreme case of alpha==90°. It will just be reflected back.
- If you refer to the ***blue line*** being the "beam", pay attention that the "blue alpha" is not equal to the "black alpha" - that'll be true only for a single angle. So "2*alpha" should be "alpha+beta", with "beta" being a constant. Then you should have the beam always hitting always the same point.